# Resource commendations for SUSY gauge theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, supersymmetry, gauge-theory

Does anyone know of recent SUSY gauge theory reviews aimed at the graduate student? Preferably something to bring the reader up to speed?

Comment: The question you have referred to is about Supersymmetry in general, not about SUSY gauge theory. To be perfectly honest, I do not see how the two are equivalent.

Comment: I don't know why you changed it back to 'SUSY.' The phrase 'supersymmetry gauge theory' doesn't make sense, it's 'supersymmetric gauge theory.'

Comment: I did type "supersymmetric", so I'm not sure how it got changed back to SUSY. Sorry!